# Cannot insert data, foreign key error on postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have 3 tables, where the table INTRUSIONS have foreign keys belonging to CCTVS and ALARMS tables. I want the foreign keys to be nullable in my INTRUSIONS table. I am not sure why but I cannot insert data into my 'INTRUSIONS' table. Here is my code:

```
CREATE  TABLE
REMOTE_SECURITY.CCTVS(CCTV_ID   serial);

CREATE  TABLE
REMOTE_SECURITY.ALARMS(ALARM_ID serial);

CREATE  TABLE
REMOTE_SECURITY.INTRUSIONS(INTRUSION_ID serial,CCTV_ID  serial,ALARM_ID serial);

ALTER   TABLE
REMOTE_SECURITY.CCTVS   ADD CONSTRAINT
CCTVS_PK    PRIMARY KEY
(CCTV_ID)
;
ALTER   TABLE
REMOTE_SECURITY.ALARMS  ADD CONSTRAINT
ALARMS_PK   PRIMARY KEY
(ALARM_ID)
;
```

This code doesn't work:

```
  INSERT
    INTO
        REMOTE_SECURITY.INTRUSIONS
    (
        INTRUSION_ID
    ,   CCTV_ID
    ,   ALARM_ID
    ) VALUES (
        1
    ,   NULL
    ,   1
    )
    ;
```

Here is the error:

```
[2018-11-19 19:35:59] [23502] ERROR: null value in column "cctv_id" violates not-null constraint
[2018-11-19 19:35:59] Detail: Failing row contains (1, null, 1, 2010-02-01 07:00:01).
```

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key forces the column to be non null.  If you want a foreign key association it won't know how to relate null to another table.  From the documentation

> A foreign key constraint specifies that the values in a column (or a group of columns) must match the values appearing in some row of another table. We say this maintains the referential integrity between two related tables.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/ddl-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

Your `Error` are clear.. You cannot put `Null` value to `Foreign Key` or `Serial`.. Maybe you are wrong in the concept design your `schema`..

```
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname SERIAL
);
```

is equivalent to specifying:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq;
CREATE TABLE tablename (
    colname integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('tablename_colname_seq')
);
ALTER SEQUENCE tablename_colname_seq OWNED BY tablename.colname;
```

As noted by [`Documentation Serial`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html#DATATYPE-SERIAL) data type hold `Not Null` so it can't be `Null` and Other answer really great tell about constraint foreign key..

As [`Documentation FK`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) said

> We say this maintains the referential integrity between two related
>   tables

So.. The value in `FK` are referencing to Parents value which it is the `PK`.. `PK` cannot have `Null` so `FK` too..

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key column (`intrusions.cctv_id` or `intrusions.alarm_id` in your case) should **not** be defined as `serial` as you don't want to generate new values every time you insert into them. You use the generated values from the referenced primary key column(s)

As dwir182 has pointed out, a `serial` column is implicitly defined as `not null`. By fixxing the incorrect definition of the FK columns, you will be able to insert NULL values.

So you want:

```
CREATE TABLE remote_security.intrusions
(
  intrusion_id   serial,
  -- no serial for the foreign key columns!
  cctv_id        integer references cctvs,
  alarm_id       integer references alarms
);
```

Then you can do the following:

```
insert into remote_security.cctvs values (default); -- creates id = 1;
insert into remote_security.alarms values (default); -- creates id = 1;

-- do not specify a value for the serial column!
insert into remote_security.intrusions 
  (intrusion_id, cctv_id, alarm_id)
values 
  (default, null, 1);
```

See the online example: https://rextester.com/ELPHK12991